# Data missing retrieving data using the API 8.2

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

1. We have a Kendo grid in CRM Dynamics which load tasks, so it sends a
   fetchXml to the API using GET.
2. Some time ago we ran into problems because the fetchXml was too long
   be sent using GET and it threw an exception.
3. We changed the way the data is retrieved. Now it uses a POST method, but a
   really weird behavior has come up.
4. If in the retrieved list the first record has the `scheduledstart ==     null`, that field is not returned by the API.
5. If it is set, all the fields are returned by the API.
6. If the first record is null and the field is not returned, but
   another task is inserted with the schedulestart with a value it,
   starts working again - same code, same fetchXml, same everything.
7. In fact,, if I execute the FetchXml in the XRMToolbox it returned the
   fields as expected.

These are my two pieces of code:

```
using get: bad request, querystring oveload
   var encodedFetchXml2 = encodeURI(fetchXml);
        var queryPath2 = "/api/data/v8.2/" + entityName + "s?fetchXml=" + encodedFetchXml2;
        var requestPath2 = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + queryPath2;
        var result2 = [];

        var req2 = new XMLHttpRequest();


        req2.open("GET", requestPath2, false);    // false: synchronous
        req2.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        req2.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
        req2.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                this.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    var returned2 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                    result2 = returned2.value;
                }
                else {
                    alert(this.statusText);
                    console.log(requestPath);
                }
            }
        };
req2.send();
            return result2;
```

using post: weird behaviour

```
 var result = [];
        var encodedFetchXml = encodeURI(fetchXml);

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/$batch", false);
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_" + entityName + "fetch");
        req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");

        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (this.status === 200) {

                    var response = JSON.parse(this.response.substring(this.response.indexOf('{'), this.response.lastIndexOf('}') + 1));

                    result = response.value;

                    //var returned = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    //result = returned.value;
                } else {
                    alert(this.statusText);
                    console.log(requestPath);
                }
            }
        };

        var body = '--batch_' + entityName + 'fetch\n'
        body += 'Content-Type: application/http\n'
        body += 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n'
        body += '\n'
        body += 'GET ' + Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + '/api/data/v8.2/' + entityName + 's?fetchXml='+ encodedFetchXml+' HTTP/1.1\n'
        body += 'Content-Type: application/json\n'           
        body += 'OData-Version: 4.0\n'
        body += 'OData-MaxVersion: 4.0\n'
        body += 'Prefer: odata.include-annotations="*"\n'
        body += '\n'
        body += '--batch_' + entityName + 'fetch--'

        req.send(body);

        return result;
```

Hope somebody knows the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: When you use fiddler, is the payload made by your code same as the one send by xrm toolbox ? Also please lets add fetchxml payload samples.

Answer (score 1):

using fiddler I get different responses for the same request depending on if the first retrieved record have nulls or not

fetchxml

```
<fetch mapping="logical" >
<entity name="annotation" >
    <attribute name="annotationid" />
    <attribute name="createdby" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="modifiedby" />
    <attribute name="modifiedon" />
    <attribute name="subject" />
    <attribute name="notetext" />
    <attribute name="filename" />
    <attribute name="objectid" />
    <order attribute="createdon" descending="true" />
    <filter type="or" />
    <link-entity name="hamiav_position" from="hamiav_positionid" to="objectid" link-type="inner" alias="rela" >
        <filter type="or" >
            <condition attribute="hamiav_positionid" operator="in" >
                <value uitype="hamiav_position" >
                    A267205E-222E-E911-80FC-005056B700A7
                </value>
            </condition>
        </filter>
    </link-entity>
</entity>
```

the first record has values in the subject and the note text

```
"@odata.context":"http://hamsrv14:5555/HAMS/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#annotations(_modifiedby_value,_objectid_value,objectid_hamiav_position,modifiedon,notetext,createdon,_createdby_value,filename,objecttypecode,subject,annotationid)","value":[

 "@odata.etag":"W/\"67757686\"","_modifiedby_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"Fernando Garc\u00eda","_modifiedby_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname":"systemuser","_modifiedby_value":"1d88be59-7f05-e711-80c8-005056b700a7","_objectid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":null,"_objectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.associatednavigationproperty":"objectid_hamiav_position","_objectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname":"hamiav_position","_objectid_value":"a267205e-222e-e911-80fc-005056b700a7","modifiedon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"10/06/2019 10:46","modifiedon":"2019-06-10T08:46:19Z","notetext":".","createdon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"10/06/2019 10:46","createdon":"2019-06-10T08:46:19Z","_createdby_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"Fernando Garc\u00eda","_createdby_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname":"systemuser","_createdby_value":"1d88be59-7f05-e711-80c8-005056b700a7","filename":"AER-AR-01-092_full asset valuation_feb 2019_FR 31090-31089-31085-31084_PARQUEVAL S.L.jpg","objecttypecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"Position","objecttypecode":"hamiav_position","subject":".","annotationid":"19460037-5c8b-e911-8105-005056b700a7","objectid_hamiav_position":{
    "hamiav_assetmanager":null,"_modifiedby_value":null,"hamiav_totalprincipal_state":null,"_ownerid_value":null,"_owningteam_value":null,"statuscode":null,"timezoneruleversionnumber":null,"hamiav_hams_positionid":null,"_createdonbehalfby_value":null,"hamiav_totalprincipal":null,"hamiav_liveoutstandingbalance_state":null,"_transactioncurrencyid_value":null,"statecode":null,"hamiav_totalaccruedinterest_state":null,"hamiav_hams_portfolioid":null,"hamiav_numberofassets_state":null,"hamiav_liveoutstandingbalance_base":null,"_hamiav_subportfolioid_value":null,"_modifiedonbehalfby_value":null,"hamiav_amrecoverystatus":null,"hamiav_totalprincipal_base":null,"hamiav_numberofassets":null,"hamiav_hams_owner":null,"hamiav_mainparticipant":null,"hamiav_portfolio":null,"hamiav_name":null,"hamiav_numberofparticipants":null,"hamiav_mainparticipantnif":null,"_owninguser_value":null,"hamiav_totalaccruedinterest_base":null,"hamiav_positionid":"a267205e-222e-e911-80fc-005056b700a7","_owningbusinessunit_value":null,"hamiav_liveoutstandingbalance":null,"versionnumber":null,"modifiedon":null,"hamiav_contactstatus":null,"hamiav_recoverystrategy":null,"utcconversiontimezonecode":null,"_createdby_value":null,"exchangerate":null,"hamiav_numberofrelatedcontracts":null,"hamiav_totalprincipal_date":null,"createdon":null,"hamiav_numberofrelatedcontracts_date":null,"hamiav_subportfoliocobra":null,"hamiav_numberofrelatedcontracts_state":null,"_hamiav_portfolioid_value":null,"hamiav_totalaccruedinterest":null,"overriddencreatedon":null,"hamiav_numberofassets_date":null,"hamiav_totalaccruedinterest_date":null,"hamiav_liveoutstandingbalance_date":null,"_hamiav_assetmanagerid_value":null,"importsequencenumber":null,"_hamiav_mainparticipantid_value":null,"hamiav_code":null,"hamiav_subportfolio":null,"hamiav_assetmanagername":null
  }
},
```

I have insert a new record with no values for subject and notetext so the first record do not contain values for that fields and the response is:

```
"@odata.context":"http://hamsrv14:5555/HAMS/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#annotations(_modifiedby_value,_objectid_value,objectid_hamiav_position,modifiedon,createdon,_createdby_value,filename,objecttypecode,annotationid)","value":[
{
  "@odata.etag":"W/\"67757548\"","_modifiedby_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"Fernando Garc\u00eda","_modifiedby_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname":"systemuser","_modifiedby_value":"1d88be59-7f05-e711-80c8-005056b700a7","_objectid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":null,"_objectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.associatednavigationproperty":"objectid_hamiav_position","_objectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname":"hamiav_position","_objectid_value":"a267205e-222e-e911-80fc-005056b700a7","modifiedon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"10/06/2019 10:14","modifiedon":"2019-06-10T08:14:28Z","createdon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"10/06/2019 10:14","createdon":"2019-06-10T08:14:28Z","_createdby_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"Fernando Garc\u00eda","_createdby_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname":"systemuser","_createdby_value":"1d88be59-7f05-e711-80c8-005056b700a7","filename":"AER-AR-01-092_full asset valuation_feb 2019_FR 31090-31089-31085-31084_PARQUEVAL S.L.jpg","objecttypecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue":"Position","objecttypecode":"hamiav_position","annotationid":"2e4ef9c3-578b-e911-8105-005056b700a7","objectid_hamiav_position":{
    "hamiav_assetmanager":null,"_modifiedby_value":null,"hamiav_totalprincipal_state":null,"_ownerid_value":null,"_owningteam_value":null,"statuscode":null,"timezoneruleversionnumber":null,"hamiav_hams_positionid":null,"_createdonbehalfby_value":null,"hamiav_totalprincipal":null,"hamiav_liveoutstandingbalance_state":null,"_transactioncurrencyid_value":null,"statecode":null,"hamiav_totalaccruedinterest_state":null,"hamiav_hams_portfolioid":null,"hamiav_numberofassets_state":null,"hamiav_liveoutstandingbalance_base":null,"_hamiav_subportfolioid_value":null,"_modifiedonbehalfby_value":null,"hamiav_amrecoverystatus":null,"hamiav_totalprincipal_base":null,"hamiav_numberofassets":null,"hamiav_hams_owner":null,"hamiav_mainparticipant":null,"hamiav_portfolio":null,"hamiav_name":null,"hamiav_numberofparticipants":null,"hamiav_mainparticipantnif":null,"_owninguser_value":null,"hamiav_totalaccruedinterest_base":null,"hamiav_positionid":"a267205e-222e-e911-80fc-005056b700a7","_owningbusinessunit_value":null,"hamiav_liveoutstandingbalance":null,"versionnumber":null,"modifiedon":null,"hamiav_contactstatus":null,"hamiav_recoverystrategy":null,"utcconversiontimezonecode":null,"_createdby_value":null,"exchangerate":null,"hamiav_numberofrelatedcontracts":null,"hamiav_totalprincipal_date":null,"createdon":null,"hamiav_numberofrelatedcontracts_date":null,"hamiav_subportfoliocobra":null,"hamiav_numberofrelatedcontracts_state":null,"_hamiav_portfolioid_value":null,"hamiav_totalaccruedinterest":null,"overriddencreatedon":null,"hamiav_numberofassets_date":null,"hamiav_totalaccruedinterest_date":null,"hamiav_liveoutstandingbalance_date":null,"_hamiav_assetmanagerid_value":null,"importsequencenumber":null,"_hamiav_mainparticipantid_value":null,"hamiav_code":null,"hamiav_subportfolio":null,"hamiav_assetmanagername":null
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you reached to any solution?